# Wordpress JQuery Ajax request readyState always 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I can't find an answer to this problem.

I'm trying to get the youtube video title (form Wordpress of course, but I want to do it from javascript). Well my code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://youtube.com/get_video_info",
    data: {video_id : v_arr[i]},
    type: 'GET',
    complete: function(jqXHR, res){
        if(jqXHR.readyState === 4) {
            alert(res);
        }
        alert(jqXHR.statusText);
    }
});
```

The problem: on 'complete' I always get readyState 0 and except for the "error" in statusText I don't get any helpful error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the url into what Circadian provided. The problem was also with i variable. As you see this is all happening inside a loop. So when the complete callback happened 'i' already had the last value from the loop... so when I accessed v_arr[i], there was the 'undefined index' problem.

The solution is "temp i":

```
for(var i=0; i<v_arr.length; i++) {
    var temp_i = i;
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+v_arr[temp_i],
        //data: {video_id : v_arr[temp_i]},
        type: 'GET',
        complete: function(jqXHR, res){
            if(jqXHR.readyState === 4) {
                alert(res);
            }
            alert(jqXHR.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the ajax you provided and I got a 301 redirect response.

Looking at the youtube api I see the url being `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/` which returns success